# MongoDB Update Array of objects if property is the same

Tags: mongodb

I want to update this document's subscribers array if property 'name' is the same as the name I specify, if not add it to the array

```js
{
    id: "Test-123456789",
    subscribers: [
        {
            name: "Test1",
            points: 123
        },
        {
            name: "Test2",
            points: 3282
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [positional operator `$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/update/positional/) like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  "id": "Test-123456789",
  "subscribers.name": yourValue
},
{
  "$set": {
    "subscribers.$.points": 0
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QHGeaeEeHC4).

Note that I've modified `points` field but using `$` you can access the object and modify as you want, like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/le-x1gkaH54)